# Adding Calculated Columns together to create a Total

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am creating a tracking sheet, based off of multiple tables. I then use a CASE statement to determine the progress of each section. I would like to then take the results of these 3 calculated col and create a Total ?

```
Select Case
     ....
End as [Val1],
Select Case
     ....
End as [Val2],
(Val1 + Val2) as [Total]
From Table
```

Currently the Addition line is not working since the Val1 and Val2 are 'Invalid Column Names'

How can I fix this ?

```
SELECT 
    d.DataSourceID as [DataSource], 
    c.Name as [Custodian Name], 
    et.Name as [Source Type], 
    ed1.QCBarcode as [ED1 QC Barcode], 
    ed1code.Name as [ED1 Status],
Case 
    When ed1code.Name like '01%' then 14
    When ed1code.Name like '02%' then 28
    When ed1code.Name like '03%' then 42
    When ed1code.Name like '04%' then 56
    When ed1code.Name like '05%' then 71
    When ed1code.Name like '06%' then 85
    When ed1code.Name like '07%' then 100
    When ed1code.Name like '08%' then 0
End  as [ed1Calc],
ed3.ProcessingCase as [ED3 LAW Case Name],  
ed3code.Name as [ED3 Status], 
Case 
    When ed3code.Name like '01%' then 50
    When ed3code.Name like '02%' then 100
    When ed3code.Name like '03%' then 0
    When ed3code.Name like '04%' then 0
End  as [ed3Calc],
ed4.ED4ID as [ED 4 Reference],  
ed4code.Name as [ED4 Status],
Case 
    When ed4code.Name like '01%' then 34
    When ed4code.Name like '02%' then 66
    When ed4code.Name like '03%' then 100
End  as [ed4Calc],
 ( (ed1Calc + ed3Calc + ed4Calc)/3 ) as [Overall Status]
/*Basic  layout */
FROM [EDDSDBO].[DataSources] d
JOIN  [EDDSDBO].[Custodian] c ON d.Custodian = c.ArtifactID
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[EvidenceType] et ON d.EvidenceType= et.ArtifactID
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[f4868106f4868107] fed1 on fed1.f4868107ArtifactID = d.ArtifactID
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ED1PreProcessingRecord] ed1 ON fed1.f4868106ArtifactID = ed1.ArtifactID
JOIN  [EDDSDBO].[ED3LawLoadingRecord] ed3 ON ed1.ArtifactID = ed3.ED1Reference
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ED4LawRelativityMigrationRecord] ed4 ON ed3.ArtifactID =    ed4.ED3Reference
 /*status*/
--ed1
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ZCodeArtifact_1000129] ed1Status  ON ed1.ArtifactID =  ed1Status.AssociatedArtifactID
JOIN  [EDDSDBO].[Code] ed1code ON ed1Status.CodeArtifactID = ed1code.ArtifactID

--ed3
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ZCodeArtifact_1000156] ed3Status  ON ed3.ArtifactID = ed3Status.AssociatedArtifactID
JOIN  [EDDSDBO].[Code] ed3code ON ed3Status.CodeArtifactID = ed3code.ArtifactID
--ed4
JOIN [EDDSDBO].[ZCodeArtifact_1000161] ed4Status ON ed4.ArtifactID = ed4Status.AssociatedArtifactID
JOIN  [EDDSDBO].[Code] ed4code ON ed4Status.CodeArtifactID = ed4code.ArtifactID
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify any specific RDBMS.

A method that should work in all/most would be to use a derived table.

```
SELECT Val1,
       Val2, 
       Val1 + Val2 AS Total
FROM 
(
Select Case
     ....
End as [Val1],
Select Case
     ....
End as [Val2]
From Table
) d /*<-- arbitrary derived table alias*/
```

Probably you are on SQL Server (from the square brackets) in which case you could also use

```
SELECT Val1,
       Val2,
       Val1 + Val2 AS Total
FROM   TABLE
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Case ....End,Case ....End)) V( Val1, Val2)
```

depending on the exact expression behind `Val1` and `Val2` (e.g. you can't use this and get correct results if they reference window functions).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have tried the 1st option with no luck, I have added the exact code in the 2nd block. The problem comes in with all my joins I think.